# Algebraic manipulations on calculating limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

On the following sequence (and similar ones): $\frac{2}{1},\frac{4}{3},\frac{6}{5},\dots \frac{2n}{2n+1}$, when we want to calculate the limit as $n\to\infty$, one usually divides both the numerator and the denominator by the highest power of the denominator.

Using the epsilon-delta definition, where this idea came from?

Comment: The idea comes from $\lim a_n+b_n = \lim a_n + \lim b_n$ and $\lim {a_n\over b_n} = {\lim a_n \over \lim b_n}$. These two are provable using the epsilon definition of limit.

Comment: So $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{2n+1} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}2n}{\lim_{n\to\infty}2n+1}$$. On the other hand, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n+1=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n + \lim_{n\to\infty} 1$$. So $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{2n+1} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}2n}{\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n + \lim_{n\to\infty} 1} \rightarrow \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n}{\lim_{n\to\infty} 2n*(1+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2n}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1+0}=0$$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

We want to be able to apply the Algebraic Limit Theorem. Specifically, we want to have two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n &= x \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n &= y,
\end{align}
where $\{y_n\}$ is eventually nonzero and $y \ne 0$, so that we can conclude
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} &= \frac{x}{y}.
\end{align}
The problem is that the sequence
\begin{align}
\frac{2n}{2n+1}
\end{align}
does not immediately satisfy this condition, since
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} 2n &= \infty \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} 2n + 1 &= \infty.
\end{align}
However, by dividing both the numerator and the denominator by $2n$ ($n > 0$), we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{2n}{2n+1} &= \frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{2n}}.
\end{align}
Now, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 &= 1, \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{2n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \\
&= 1 + 0 \\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Here we use the Algebraic Limit Theorem to establish that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{2n} = 1$, but in a much more straightforward way. Notice, however, that these two results allow us to conclude that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{2n + 1} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+ \frac{1}{2n}} \\
&= \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} 1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \frac{1}{2n}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1} \\
&= 1,
\end{align}
as we needed.